# How to specify the subject of an `at` job

Tags: at

The [man page for `at`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) says :

> The user will be mailed standard error and standard output from his commands, if any. Mail will be sent using the command /usr/sbin/sendmail.

This is working fine, but the subject line in the emails is generic:

> `Subject: Output from your job       10`

How do I make the subject something descriptive of my choosing?

I'm using Debian 8.

Comment: After reading the `at` manual, I'm not sure that's possible...

Comment: The use of the mail command is hard coded in the `at` command (see `strings \`which at\``). Get the sources, modify to your needs, and compile - seems to be the only way.

Comment: You *could* use `procmail` to process the mail on its way to your mailbox and, eg, replace the subject by the first line in the body of the mail.